# How to rigorously prove that there there infinitely many theorems of PA?

Tags: logic

By PA, I mean Peano Arithmetic. Suppose we are working within a logical system, like ZFC, that can rigorously define what a first-order logical system is, in particular, PA. How does one rigorously prove that there are infinitely many theorems of PA? I apologize if this question is too elementary and/or pedantic.

Comment: Would it suffice to prove that there is at least one theorem, and that if $\sigma$ is a theorem then $\sigma\land\sigma$ is also a theorem?

Comment: I mean, 1+1=2, and 1+1+1=3, and 1+1+1+1=4... those are all theorems of PA.

Comment: @bof Yes, that would be sufficient.

Comment: 1=1, 2=2, 3=3,...